# In which order are variables assigned in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment

Apparently this is identical in my Firebug console:

```
var x = "A", y = x;
x + y === "AA";
```

and

```
var x = y, y = "A";
x + y === "AA";
```

Is this standard ECMAScript behaviour, that the order doesn't play a role in comma-separated `var` assignments?

**Edit:** The "mystery" is solved. I tested the first example first, then cleared the console and ran the second. However, at this time, `y` and `x` were already defined. If you run the JSFiddle provided by David Thomas you always get an "undefinedA". Case settled.

Comment: It seems to matter in Chromium 12, on Ubuntu 11.04: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pMPbE/). `alert(x + y)` results in `undefinedA` in the alert.

Comment: This fiddle, too, doesn't work in FF. Strange behaviour, this.

Comment: Actually, now when trying to retrace the issue, I can't, seems like the variable value itself is passed and not reference. That's odd I could've sworn it acted differently before. Anyway, I can't seem to trace the problem on Chrome. Very odd indeed.

Comment: @Boldewyn, are you sure `window.y` is not equal to `A`?

Comment: If you ran your tests without resetting in the middle somewhere it explains the behavior.  `y` would still have existed from your previous assignment, allowing the second form to work.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi you, sir, are a genious. When I tested it, I started with the first assignment, and that set `window.y`. Then, the second example of course used window.x and window.y. Could you post it as answer?

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin: Primitives like strings aren't passed by reference. Only objects (objects, arrays, functions, ...) are.

Comment: This all could've been avoided with absurd and unique variable names in each example.

Comment: @Yar, yes of course. But in hindsight everyone is smarter. I wondered for some time, in which order variables should be declared, so I tried to formulate a minimal and consistent test case, unfortunately flawed.

Comment: @Boldewyn, sorry, I forgot to put a smiley. My point was ironic, but it is kind of funny that serious-looking code gets you into problems precisely (well, kind of) because it's serious-looking. But legitimate question and +1 and all that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var x = y;` will raise an exception if `y` is not defined.

However, the [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window) object is the default context for Javascript interpreters embedded in browsers. If you previously issued:

```
y = "A";
```

Then you actually assigned `"A"` to `window.y`, therefore `var x = y;` becomes valid and assigns `window.y` to `x`.